# Absolute values on $p$-adic numbers

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I would like to have a classification of absolute values on the field $\Bbb Q_p$ of $p$-adic numbers (for any prime $p$).

I guess that such an absolute value is either equivalent to the trivial one, or equivalent to the usual $p$-adic absolute value.
(Recall that two absolute values $|\cdot|_1$ and $|\cdot|_2$ on a field $F$ are equivalent if and only if there is a real number $s > 0$ such that $|x|_1 = |x|_2^s$ for every $x \in F$. See Neukirch's *Algebraic Number Theory*, proposition 3.3, chapter II.)

I know that if $| \cdot |$ is an absolute value on $\Bbb Q_p$, it gives an absolute value on $\Bbb Q$, hence is equivalent to the trivial one or to $| \cdot |_p$ for some $p \leq \infty$ by Ostrowski's theorem. But why doesn't $| \cdot |_q$ extend to $\Bbb Q_p$ when $q \neq p$? I see that I cannot extend it directly, because of a continuity issue (here I wanted to use density of $\Bbb Q$ is $\Bbb Q_p$), but after all, an absolute value is not required to be continuous in any sense.

Comment: $|\cdot|_q$ does extend to $\Bbb Q_p$ for $q\ne p$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown : even if $q = \infty$? And is _one_ (or the?) extension of $|.|_q$ equivalent to $| . |_p$?

Comment: Yes, no.${}{}{}$

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown : thank you for your comment. Is it true that any two extensions of $|.|_q$ are equivalent absolute values of $\Bbb Q_p$?

Comment: 1) I have seen that given a valuation on a field (or any absolute value (not necessarily non-archimedian?), one can extend it to _any_ field extension (not necessarily algebraic!) ; 2) If $|.|_q$ is equivalent to $|.|_p$ on $\Bbb Q_p$ then $\Bbb Z_p$ has to be bounded for $|.|_q = |.|_p^s$, one can probably conclude that $q=p$ from this.

Comment: Although one can extend $q$-adic valuations to $\Bbb Q_p$, they would be discontinuous there, and since one needs Zorn-type arguments to create them, there is little one can say about them.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown : one more question, if you don't mind : on the other hand, is any absolute value $|.| : \Bbb Q_p \to \Bbb R$, which is continuous with respect to the $p$-adic topology, equivalent to $|.|_p$ ?

Comment: Answer to last question: yes.

Comment: @Lubin : thank you very much! I see that $p^n \to 0$ implies (by continuity of $|.|$) $|p| < 1$, so WLOG $|p| = 1/p$. Then I only need to show that any unit $u$ of $\Bbb Z_p$ has absolute value $1$. Since $\Bbb Z_p$ is compact and $|.|$ is continuous, it has bounded image. But why does it follow that $|u| = 1$ ?

Comment: Well, take a unit with $|u|\ne1$, we may assume $>1$. Its powers form an unbounded set, contradicting the boundedness of the group of units.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/338148/96384