# Is $\mathbb{Q}_p$ isomorphic to a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ for some prime number $p$?

Tags: complex-numbers, field-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Is there a prime number $p$, such that $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is isomorphic to a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: No.  $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed, whereas $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is not.  You could ask the same question with respect to $\mathbb{C}$ and the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, but the answer remains no, though for slightly more complicated reasons.

Comment: @Xander: I'm assuming that you mean "homeomorphic" when you read "homomorphic"?

Comment: The idea was to ask if Q_p is isomorphic to some subfield of C, sorry if i expressed myself impropertly

Comment: That usage of "homomorphic" is not correct.  I have edited to make the meaning clear.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/338148/is-there-an-explicit-embedding-from-the-various-fields-of-p-adic-numbers-mathb might be worth a look.

Comment: I don't see an answer to this question at the "algebraically closed" question. Is this question really a duplicate of that one?

Comment: if i understood correctly the statement of the question you gave me link to (and the top answer), the answer is yes for every p, but can't be explicitly constructed.