# On the existence of an algebraically closed field containing other fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, real-numbers, p-adic-number-theory

This question arose while I was reading a paper I found in the web.
It might be very simple, but I don't know the answer.
Let $\mathbb{R}$ be the set of real numbers and $\mathbb{Q}_p$ the set of all $p$-adic numbers.

My question is: how can I construct (or at least guarantee the existence of) an algebraically closed field $\Omega$ of characteristic $0$ containing both $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}_p$ for all primes $p$?

More generally, given a finite or infinite family of fields with the same characteristic (and possibly a common subfield), can I prove the existence of such a field? If not, under which conditions does it hold?

Thank you in advance for your help.

**Edit:** about my background, my level is basic; that is, I know what an algebraically closed field is and basic facts about Field Theory from a basic Galois theory course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to embed the algebraic closure of $\Bbb Q_p$ into $\Bbb C$, if you want. We also can consider the *completion* $\Bbb C_p$ of $\overline{\Bbb Q_p}$. This field is called the field of $p$-adic complex numbers.

The details have been already discussed at this site, e.g., here:

[Is there an explicit embedding from the various fields of p-adic numbers $\mathbb{Q}_p$ into $\mathbb{C}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/338148/is-there-an-explicit-embedding-from-the-various-fields-of-p-adic-numbers-mathb)

The embedding is guaranteed by the axiom of choice.

Comment: Can you explain in more details this construction? (A reference would be appreciated) I mean, once you have embedded each $\mathbb{Q}_p$ in $\mathbb{C}_p$, how can I "glue" them to get an algebrically closed field containig them all? (I think in the same way I can proceed for $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Just embed each $\Bbb Q_p$ into $\Bbb C$ and you are done.

Comment: Sorry, but how is the embedding defined? Once it is defined, does it mean that $\Omega =\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: The embedding is given by the axiom of choice.

Comment: Ok, I've found an answer to the embedding problem. Last question: please, can you say to me how can I obtain $\Omega $ from this?

Comment: I have defined $\Omega$ in the question as the algebrically closed field of characteristic $0$ containjng both $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}_p$ for all primes $p$.

Comment: Wow!! Well, to summarize up, $\Omega =\mathbb{C}$. Thank you very much. I upvote your answer. Now I'm very very curious about that: is there a standard reference for the proof of the embedding above?

Comment: Yes, there are several standard references. On MO for example, the proof is given in the first six lines of [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23264/are-c-and-barq-p-isomorphic). But of course, the problem for many people here is, that it relies on the axiom of choice (and not on much more).